# dynamically creating SVG circle with multiple segments using <g> and <use> -how to achieve animation?

Tags: angular, svg, svg-animate, stroke-dasharray

I am trying create a SVG in Angular8.

It should look circles facing each other. I created 2 circles with computed segments like this:

```
<svg>
<style>
#leftCircle {
 transition: stroke-dasharray 3s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.5, 0.2 ,1.5) 
}
</style>
<defs>
<circle id="leftCircle" [attr.r] ="r1" /> 
<circle id="RightCircle" [attr.r] ="r2" /> 
</defs>
<g id="circle-group" fill="none transform="translate(20,20)">
    <use x="50" y="50" *ngFor ="let segment of segments: index as i" id="segment--{{segment.segmentid}}
    [attr.stroke-dasharray]=getStrokeArray(i) [attr.stroke-dashOffset]=getDashOffset(i)
    [attr.stroke]=getStrokeColor(i) [attr.stroke-width]=x></use>
    <use x="50" y="50" 
    [attr.stroke-dasharray]=getStrokeArray1(i) [attr.stroke-dashOffset]=getDashOffset1(i)
    [attr.stroke]=getStrokeColor1(i) [attr.stroke-width]=y></use>


</g>
 </svg>
```

What I would like to do:

Create an animation effect that is a "slow drawing effect" from segment to segment.

I tried unsuccessfully to add transition in the `<style>` tag to create the drawing effect

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Hi Kapyar, glad to have you around. To improve your odds of getting an answer you need to add your source code. I put a placeholder in your text where you can add it

Comment: I tried to follow couple of posts but I could not find which has multiple dynamically created circles with animation

Comment: Add the code you have